# Website access with http and https

Tags: ssl, https, xampp

I have a WordPress website which is hosted on an Apache Xampp Server, Windows 2012 Server R2. I have put SSL on it and I have added `https://www.example.com` as the `siteurl` in Settings.

I can access the home page of the website with both `http://www.example.com` and `https://www.example.com`, but I can not access other pages like:

- http://www.example.com/about
- http://www.example.com/contact
- http://www.example.com/bank

Although, all these are accessible using `https`.

How can I make them accessible with both `http` and `https`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that this is happening is that WordPress will always use the 'siteurl' whenever you navigate past the home page. AFAIK there is no way around this to make the pages accessible from multiple urls. If you only want the ssl on certain pages, there are plugins for that. Besides, if you've paid for the ssl on the site why would you want to make it optional for visitors?